# Named import is undefined when default export and named export are both used

Tags: vue.js, ecmascript-6, vuejs2, node-modules

According to [this book](http://exploringjs.com/es6/ch_modules.html#_default-ok-as-export-name-but-not-as-variable-name), default export and named export can exist at the same time.

However, when I try it, the named import is always undefined. I use vue single file components. My full code is in [codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/zrk5voxqj4).

#### TestModule.vue

```html
<script>
export default {};
export const test1 = '111';
</script>
```

#### App.vue

```html
<template>
  <div id="app">
  </div>
</template>

<script>
import test, { test1 } from './TestModule.vue';
// import test, { test1 } from './TestModule.js';

console.log(test, test1);

export default {
  name: "App",
};
</script>
```

I think maybe it is because export works different in vue. So I try to use js file with the same code (see TestModule.js). Then it works.

But my colleague says he can export and import default and named export in vue files at the same time normally. He guesses it may be because webpack is not properly configured.

So how to make it work? Is this codesandbox's problem?

Comment: Your `TestModule` should just be a JS module, not a single-file Vue component

Comment: @Phil That's what I want to do. I want to import named constants from a vue component. The code is used to demonstrate the problem.

Comment: Deleted my answer because it seems vue-loader **does** support named exports since [13.6.0](https://github.com/vuejs/vue-loader/releases/tag/v13.6.0). [This comment here](https://github.com/vuejs/vue-loader/issues/1434#issuecomment-449706020) indicates it might be an issue with CodeSandbox